# How do I find changesets between two TFS branches?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to get a list of all changesets that are different between two different TFS branches? I'm not talking about file differences.

I have a main code base (MAIN). I create a new branch from that called (MAIN-BRANCH). I create another branch called (RELEASE). I check-in five times to MAIN-BRANCH, then merge to MAIN.

I want to pull all the changeset comments that have occurred between RELEASE and MAIN.

Answer (score 0):

can you use the TF merges command to do this for you:

tf merges branchroot1 branchroot2 /recursive

See the [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx) command for more help.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2005 this isn't possible, comments and changeset details are not passed from branch to branch.  You have to look in the branch the changesets occurred in and compare the dates to find the ones you want.